# What is best way to fill in data from database (sql server 2008) to word (word 2007 / template)?

Tags: database, templates, ms-word

I need to read data from my DB (MS SQL server 2008) and push them into Word document (Office 2007). What is the best and fast way to do it? I have read about the problem here : support.microsoft.com/kb/316384 and here : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192487(office.11).aspx. I have tried to understand also use of [fleXdoc](http://flexdoc.codeplex.com/), but there is almost no documentation. I do not need to use it on server, i want generate locally. I will generate maximally 10 separate documents from template at maximum 5 pages per each. (Invoice for example). Please can someone point to some how-to or sample project, as i am unable to find something usefull. Thank`s a lot.

Comment: Ok I have figured it out. I have created class (ExportInvoice) with items wanted in my docx document. After click on PrintInvoice, i am mapping details from UI to this export class, then serialize this class to xml (XmlSerializer). At the end, i have created docx document marked with xpath tags, mapping xml structure (ExportInvoice class). And finally i have used fleXdoc to merge my exported xml data and tagged word docx template. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CustomXML databinding, but you will likely need to be able to handle repeating rows of data.  That can be done (see http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/sample-docs/databinding/conventions.html ), but may be overkill for your scenario.

What about making an HTML document for your data table, and including that in your Word document as an altChunk?  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx

Both of these approaches work with Word 2007 or later, using docx (Open XML) as the document format.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you output text files, CSV for example, and use those for your merge data files for Word.

Answer (score 0):

Something to be aware of however, the approach might not work with Office 2010. MS Had to remove a lot of the Custom XML merging stuff from Word as a result of a lawsuit about the technology. Updates to Office 2007 and definitely 2010 have some parts of that XML support removed.

Comment: Yes, that`s true, but for now, i`ll be using Office 2007 and i think it should do the trick for now :)